# Eclipse PDT/PHP Getting XXX cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: eclipse-pdt

I really should know better.  Every time I started Eclipse it was prompting me for updates.  I was on Oxygen, and I thought, OK, I'll update.  After it restarted, it gave me the Eclipse Photon logo, and now there are many errors telling me it cannot resolve types, following is an example

```
class MyException extends Exception {
    public $error_code, $desc;
    function __construct($desc);
    {
        parent::__construct($desc);
        $this->error_code = $error_code;
        $this->desc = $desc;
     }
}
```

In the above code Exception is flagged.  It marks it as an error "Exception could not be resolved to a type"

There have been multiple solutions that I have been through the most cited is on that says to add the following to a .buildpath file in your project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<buildpath>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
</buildpath>
```

Which did not resolve the issue.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04, running PDT6.0, on Eclipse 4.8.0 (Photon) Build 20180619-1200

Any thoughts on what the issue is.  I've use MyException in a lot of places and it's causing a bunch of code that runs fine to be marked w/ errors.

There are many other functions that are from included libraries and from PHP core that are reporting "Could not be resolve to a type", but I thought Exception was a good example because it should be resolved in PHP core.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this ?

Comment: Nope, no resolution yet.